# Android custom empty cicrle progress bar color issue

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-custom-view

I have custom circle progressbar in Android which I made with drawable circular.xml

Here is my progressbar:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/circle_progress_id"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:rotation="-90"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkbox_id"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"/>
```

Here is code from @drawable/circular

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3.4"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="9.0"
            android:useLevel="true" >
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#4CAF50"
                android:startColor="#4CAF50"
                android:type="sweep"
                android:useLevel="true" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And it works fine and show progress after:

```
recyclerTaskHolder.progressBarStage.setProgress(getStageProgressValue(myTask));
```

But it absolutely empty when it is zero progress.
I need to show for user empty gray color progress bar when it is zero progress. Or show empty part of progress bar with gray color when it is between zero and 100%.

I tried to make custom background of progress bar

```
android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
```

Here is circle_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3.4"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="9.0"
            android:useLevel="true"
            android:visible="true">
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:type="sweep"
                android:useLevel="true" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

But it didn't help me and empty progress bar is still invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't find the reason of this issue. 
But I use this library for Circle Progress Bar and it works fine.
[CircularProgressBar](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar)

It is easy to use this library.